# Comparing an objects center to a point?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've tried this.

```
if (crackerButton.center == CGPoint(190,135)) {
//Do something 
}
```

Didn't work.

Any ideas?

Cheers
Newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you're making a Christmas app then?

```
if (crackerButton.center == CGPointMake(190, 135)) {
//Do something 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
if(CGPointEqualToPoint(crackerButton.center, CGPointMake(190,135)))
{
    //Do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CGPointMake function](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPointMake) to create a CGPoint.

```
if (crackerButton.center == CGPointMake(190, 135)) {
  ...
```

Comment: You can't compare CGPoints like this. Instead use CGPointEqualToPoint()